# Collect data from object separated by comma and make themselves as individual object - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array contening various objects. These objects contain data separated by comma. I would like to remove each of these data from Object and make them as an individual object (including same date):

```
Array = [3]
 0: Object { year: "march 2019", "turnover": 120, "employee": 1000, "cars":232 }
 1: Object { year: "april 2019", "turnover": 123, "employee": 1340, "cars":682 }
 2: Object { year: "june 2019", "turnover": 1343, "employee": 760, "cars": 4345 }
```

my goal is to extract data from each object and make them object himself with the same date:

```
Array = [9]
 0: Object { year: "march 2019", "turnover": 120 }
 1: Object { year: "march 2019" , "employee": 1000 }
 2: Object { year: "march 2019", "cars":232 }
 3: Object { year: "april 2019", "turnover": 123 }
 4: Object { year: "april 2019", "employee": 1340 }
 5: Object { year: "april 2019","cars":682 }
 6: Object { year: "june 2019", "turnover": 1343 }
 7: Object { year: "june 2019", "employee": 760 }
 8: Object { year: "june 2019","cars": 4345 }
```

I appreciate your help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of object destructuring and `Object.keys()` combined with a simple iteration:

```js
var array = [
   { year: "march 2019", "turnover": 120, "employee": 1000, "cars":232 },
   { year: "april 2019", "turnover": 123, "employee": 1340, "cars":682 },
   { year: "june 2019", "turnover": 1343, "employee": 760, "cars": 4345 }
];

var result = [];

array.forEach((entry) => {
  
  var { year, ...rest } = entry;
  Object.keys(rest).forEach((key) => result.push({ year, [key]: rest[key] }));
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you please explain the entire arr.forEach part ???. it'd be very helpfull. i can't understand { year, [key]: rest[key] } part.....

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, it works well. I had no idea about syntax of " ...rest"

Comment: I would like to ask you as well, do you know how to delete definitively for exemple every data named "turnover" ? I tried with splice function but didn't work. Thanks

Comment: If you want to remove the `turnover` entries from the `result` array, you can do it with `.filter()`: `result = result.filter((e) => !e.turnover)`

Comment: @SarathAntony the first line in the `.forEach()` is just an object destructuring. The second part iterates over every key in the `rest` object (all keys except `year`) and pushes every key as a new object to the resulting array. The `{ [key]: rest[key] }` syntax means: create an object with a key name stored in the `key` variable and value stored in the `rest` object under `key` key

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek, thank u for your update.. what i don't understand is how come employee and car is not in the row..

Answer (score 0):

```
var testarr = [{ year: "march 2019", "turnover": 120, "employee": 1000, "cars":232 },{ year: "march 2019", "turnover": 120, "employee": 1000, "cars":232 }]

var finalArr = [];
for(i=0;i<testarr.length;i++){

    for (key in testarr[i]){
        var yearjson = { "year" : testarr[i]["year"]}
        if(key != "year"){
            yearjson[key] = testarr[i][key]
            finalArr.push(yearjson)
        } 
    } 

}
console.log(finalArr)
```